# Processar vários pedidos simultâneo e armazenar na BD

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou a lidar com um problema novo devido alguns desafios novos que me prôpus...

Desenvolvi um sistema de cadastramento e obviamente no futuro poderá a vir ter mais de 100 cadastros por dia ou até mesmo por hora ou segundo. Pensando nisso, eu fiz um teste em pcs diferentes e fiz o cadastro ao mesmo tempo usando os dois pcs, o que aconteceu foi, a requisição do pc1 armazenou mas a requisição do pc2 não.

Eu gostaria de uma ajuda de como posso enfileirar e depois processar os pedidos, caso forem mais de 1 em simultâneo...

Uso o jQuery para enviar o formulário PHP e a BD é o mysql.

No código PHP, está o código normal para inserir dados numa BD com PDO

Código JS

```
    $.post("https://servidor/pasta/codigo.php", {
        nome: $nome,
        idade: $idade
}, function(dado){
      $("#msg").html("Inserido com sucesso");
})
```

Abraços e agradecimentos antecipados

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o PHP e JS que tens? A não ser que tenhas conseguido enviar o pedido exatamente no mesmo milisegundo não vejo porque possa ter falhado um pedido e o outro não. Tens de colocar mais código...

Comment: @Sergio .. feito...  Não acredito que tenha sido no mesmo milisegundo mas o clique nos dois pcs, foram...

Comment: Bom também informar o ocorrido na requisição dois, deu erro ? Qual ? Apenas não gravou ?

Comment: @Motta, apenas não gravou!

Answer (score 1):

Isso que você falou não faz muito sentido, o servidor, **dependendo de sua configuração**, pode "servir" centenas/milhares de requisições simultâneas. Se estiver usando `apache` por exemplo, a diretiva `MaxClients` fala o seguinte:

> A diretiva *MaxClients* seta o quantidade de requisições simultâneas que será servida.
>   Quando esse total for atingido, a conexão excedente entrará em uma fila, o tamanho dessa fila pode ser configurado pela diretiva *ListenBacklog*.

O fato de dois clientes efetuarem uma requisição simultânea ao servidor não é um problema, caso isso ocorra, o servidor irá criar **outro processo** que será responsável pelo processamento.

A questão é, a não ser que ambos scripts efetuem operações de disco que requeiram um `lock` (que não é o seu caso), não existe técnica de sincronismo que deve ser efetuado.

Existem casos que é necessário por questões transacionais da base de dados efetuar um tratamento especial para prevenção que dados quebrem a integridade (o que também que não é o caso seguindo o seu exemplo).

O problema em questão é muito amplo, talvez seja um problema no seu teste, quem sabe. A questão que eu quis demonstrar nesse texto é quase com absoluta certeza que não é um problema de sincronismo a não ser que seu servidor esteja mal configurado.

Comment: eu uso o Percona Server .. E esse teste está a ser feito remotamente. Seguindo a tua explicação, quer dizer, que se forem feitas cerca de 100 ou mais requisições ao mesmo tempo, era suposto as 100 ou mais requisições, inserirem na base de dados?

Comment: @C-lioGarcia em teoria, sim, mas existem configurações envolvidas em ambos tecnologias, como falei o `webserver` deve aceitar essa quantidade de requisições, assim como o mysql deve aceitar, esse em específico possui também uma variável que efetua esse controle chamada `max_connections`, porém diferentemente do apache se nesse número for estourado um erro será retornado. Como você comentou que não houve erro então acredito que esse limite não tenha sido extrapolado.

Comment: no código php ou no jQuery não tem como gerir essa demanda?